# looping through a list of integers in python and return two new lists

Tags: python

I want loop through a list of integers e.g list = [1, -9, 2, 3, 4, -5] and print/retun two new separate lists e.g a list of positive items and another list of negative items e.g [-9, -5] and [1, 2, 3, 4]

The code below is not working properly, please help...

```
def manipulate_data(list):
positives = []
negative = []

for item in list:
    negative.append(item if item < 0 else positives.append(item))
    print(positives)
    print(negative)
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Set aside the fun ternary operator for a moment and use traditional Python syntax, and I think you'll have better luck.

Comment: no error but the result is

Comment: [None, -9, None]
[1, 2, 3]
[None, -9, None, None]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[None, -9, None, None, None]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[None, -9, None, None, None, -5]

Answer (score 2):

That line of code won't work. One solution could be to use the simple `if-else` structure like this:

```
for item in list:
    if item < 0:
        negative.append(item)
    else:
        positives.append(item)
    print(positives)
    print(negative)
```

Comment: `negative.append()` expects an object, and it's getting one.

Comment: `positives.append(item)` won't return any object

Comment: It returns `None`.

Comment: Ok, my bad, edited

Answer (score 1):

```
def manipulate_data(list):
    positives = []
    negative = []

    for item in list:
        negative.append(item) if item < 0 else positives.append(item)

    print(positives)
    print(negative)
```

Right parenthesis of append should change its position.